# Is there a way to only clear a localstorage value rather than the whole key with Cypress?

Tags: local-storage, cypress

I am currently trying to clear a localstorage value/token with Cypress but I can only see a way to delete the whole key - this is the code I have so far:

```
it('Confirm users are logged out after 8 hours (delete last login token)', () => {

    cy.wait(2000)

    cy.clearLocalStorage('lastLogin')
  });
```

Does anyone know of a way to just target the value of this key?

Answer (score 0):

Try to override its value with something like this:

```
cy.window().then(w => w.localStorage.setItem('lastLogin', {}));
```